# How to add specific object to child?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an object like this:

```
items: [
                {
                    title: 'Parent',
                    content: {
                        title: 'Child1',
                        content: [
                            {
                                title: 'Child2',
                                content: {
                                    newFea: 'Child3'
                                },
                            },
                            {
                                title: 'Child2',
                                content: {
                                    newFea: 'Child3'
                                },
                            },
                            {
                                title: 'Child2',
                            },
                            {
                                title: 'Child2',
                                content: {
                                    newFea: 'Child3'
                                },
                            },
                            {
                                title: 'Child2',
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                },
         



 ],
```

And in the front end, each Child2 has its own button. When the switch is button clicked, I want to add Child3 to their content with this { newFea: '' },

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

first: when render UI by the array ,use indexs as the dataset,the indexs includes all parent index  of current child and index of it;

second: when click the button,split the indexs to an index array ,then foreach the array ,and find which child2 been clicked,then insert a child3 into it ,then rerender the UI;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Vue.js for your front end, you are most probably using the `v-for` directive to render lists directly.

```
<li v-for="(item, index) in items"> </li>
```

As shown above, you can use the index property in the callback function to pass an index prop to your component during render:

```
<MyComponent
  v-for="(item, index) in items"
  :index="index"
   :key="item.id"
/>
```

Inside your component, use the onClick event handler of your button to fetch the index of that particular component and add a new child to the original object.

```
props:{
  index: Number
}
methods: {
  onclick(event) {
   // This line may change depending on how you pass 'items' into this component
    items[0].content[index].content = { newFea: 'Child3' }                               
 },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button v-for="item in child2" @click="clickBtn(item)">
    {item.title}}
</button>

clickBtn(item){
    this.$set(item,'content',{ newFea: 'Child3'});
}
```